# How do you change the the icon of a non-pinned program?

Tags: windows-7, icons, taskbar

I've got separate installations of Firefox from version 3.6 all the way up to version 10 (so far!). These are for testing purposes. I've managed to change the icons from versions 3.6 to 9 (7 in total!) to a custom icon with the version number so when I have multiple versions open I can easily tell which is which. I can't for the life of me remember how to do this though! I've just installed version 10 and I can't change its icon without pinning it to the taskbar. None of the other custom icons are pinned and they always override the default Firefox icon when I launch it.

I seem to remember that I need to either add an icon to a particular folder or delete the default one that gets created but I can't remember which or where the folder is (if I'm right).

In C:\Users{My User Name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar I have only the icons I want pinned.

I've tried pinning the program, changing the icon and the name of the shortcut and then unpinning it but it always reverts back to the standard icon.

I have custom icons for all versions on my desktop and in my Start menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since nothing I did worked I tried reinstalling Firefox 10. I let it create its own icons on the desktop and start menu, then I changed the icon from the taskbar (right-click program icon on taskbar, right-click on program name in pop-up menu, select properties, change icon) on its first run. Now it's not pinned but I have a custom icon for it just like the others! The answer seems to be to let the program create its own shortcuts rather than adding a link manually, then edit the existing shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried pinning the program, changing the icon and the name of the shortcut and then unpinning it but it always reverts back to the standard icon.

Yes, if you change the icon of the pinned shortcut and then unpin the shortcut, the shortcut will be deleted, taking your custom icon along with it.

Remember that the Windows shell only allows you to assign custom icons to a *shortcut* to an application. If you want to change the icon associated with the actual executable, you need to use a resource editor such as [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) or [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/) (actually an icon editor, but it has a resource editor built in).

The simpler (and non-destructive) solution is just to create a new shortcut and change its icon.

Comment: I've already got short-cuts for all my other icons. I'm trying to replicate what I did before but now can't remember. When I open the short-cut icon for FFs 3.6 to 9 I get the custom icons (7 different ones!) on the taskbar, when I open the short-cut icon for FF 10 (created the same way) I get the default Firefox icon on the taskbar. What did I do differently before to get the custom icons on the taskbar without having to pin the programs? I've never used ResEdit or IcoFX. There is a simple way as I've already got the results on my desktop, I just need to do the same thing again!

Comment: Was it something to do with adding a link to a short-cut? When I try that Windows complains and says I can't do that.

Comment: One difference I've just noticed is that right-clicking on most non-pinned icons and then right-clicking on the program name and selecting Properties brings up the properties of the short-cut. Only Firefox 10 is giving me the exe properties. It's remembered "exe" somewhere. I need to find that location and delete the entry.